# Create guest order in the backend with magento

Tags: magento

Is it possible to create an order for guests in the backend without the customer email?

I know how to create orders for registered or new users but most of the time I need to create an order without knowing the customer's email.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento requires an email address to complete an order (and uses that email address elsewhere, depending on it entirely). You could hack it by using some store email address or a temporary email address, but you'll have to enter one.

Comment: I don't mind entering the admin email but magento says that a user with this email already exists. Is there a workaround for using an existing email address for guest order?

Comment: If you are using gmail, you can use arbitrary suffixes for email addresses with a + (e.g. your.email+customername@somegmaildomain.com)

Comment: I can't ask the store admin to do that. It feels too dirty.

Comment: I guess it's just a bad design in magento and there is no easy way around it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Without making changes to the code, you could achieve this by using an internal convention (similar to @Joseph's answer but a little cleaner) e.g.

firstname.lastname@guest.insertstoredomainnamehere.com

You could configure your mail server or MX records to drop emails sent to the "guest." subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the javascript required field validation from the email address when placing admin orders, Magento will generate a dummy email address for the customer.

This functionality looks to be deprecated as of 1.4.0.0 so test this on your version.